# Add babel polyfill to React Native Project

Tags: react-native, babeljs

I´m having a issue on android. Got this error:

> undefined is not a function(evaluating '_iterator2typeof
>   Symbol==='function'?Symbol.iterator:'@@iterator'´)

I think it is related to the use of for of, es6.

Can i add `babel-polyfill` to React Native Project ?

Answer (score 6):

In order to add [babel-polyfill](http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/) to your react-native project after installing

`npm install --save babel-polyfill`

just import it like this in your **entry endpoint**:

`import 'babel-polyfill';`

Now you can use new built-ins like `Promise` or `WeakMap`, static methods like `Array.from` and instance methods like `Array.prototype.includes`, etc.

Comment: Do we still need this with latest react-native? Or are they included by default?

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
npm install es6-symbol --save
```

Then add in your **index.android.js** & **index.ios.js**

```
import 'es6-symbol/implement'
```