# Is the lack of polyfill support for ES6's codePointAt() and fromCodePoint() in Babel on React Native a bug?

Tags: react-native, unicode, ecmascript-6, babeljs, polyfills

I discovered that two EcmaScript 6 Unicode functions work in my React Native app in Android but not iOS.

[`codePointAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/codePointAt) and [`fromCodePoint()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint)

Since Babel is a transpiler that's supposed to make ES6 syntax available on to various JavaScript engines, is this omission a bug in Babel?

Or does Babel have some more subtle concept of subsets of ES6 of which React Native does not by default include this part?

So is this lack a bug? Should I report it to Babel or to React Native?

(Yes I've rolled my own polyfill for now, so this question is only about whether having to do this is a bug.)

Comment: According to [core-js docs](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#ecmascript-6-string), used by [babel-polyfill](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill), `String#codePointAt` should be polyfilled, if you indeed included babel-polyfill, and not only used babel transpiler, which doesn't include polyfills, but only transforms syntax.

Comment: @Kaiido: Thanks. I'm just using React Native and Expo out of the box so I don't explicitly use `babel-polyfill` or anything else. Just what's included with a default install. Do you know where I look to see whether it's being used or not?

Comment: I don't know react-native, but it seems it doesn't include babel-polyfill by default. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37731475/add-babel-polyfill-to-react-native-project